# CSS animation Reverse a given letter after a set time

Tags: css

```css
{
    padding: 20px;
}
.elementToFadeInAndOut {
    -webkit-animation: fadeinout 10s linear forwards;
    animation: fadeinout 10s linear forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeinout {
    0%, 100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@keyframes fadeinout {
    0%, 100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
span {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px;
    padding: 3px;
}
.a {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    direction: rtl;
}
.b {
    -webkit-transform 5s: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.c {
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<section class="elementToFadeInAndOut">
    <span class="d">
    <span class="d">C</span>
    <span class="d">O</span>
    <span class="d">L</span>
    <span class="d">L</span>
    <span class="d">E</span>
    <span class="d">C</span>
    <span class="d">T</span>
    <span class="d">I</span>
    <span class="d">V</span>
    <span class="d">E</span>
    <span class="d"></span>
    <span class="d">M</span>
    <span class="d">E</span>
    <span class="d">M</span>
    <span class="d">O</span>
    <span class="b">R</span>
    <span class="d">Y</span>
    <span class="d"></span>
    <span class="d"></span></span><br><br>
</section>
```

Objective get the .b css class to reverse the letter R  5s  after fade in
once the letter b is  reversed the whole text fades out

Currently the whole text fades in and out fine however the letter R is already reversed.

The letter R ( with .b class)  needs to flip half way through the fade in fade out

Answer (score 2):

Add an `transform rotateY animation` to your `.b class` which can be `delayed` using `animation-delay` of `5s`.

```
.b{  
   -webkit-transform :rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
   -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-animation:rt 2s forwards 5s;
    }
@-webkit-keyframes rt {
  from{
    -webkit-transform :rotateY(180deg);
  }
  to{
    -webkit-transform :rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
```

```css
     { padding: 20px; } 

  .elementToFadeInAndOut {
   -webkit-animation: fadeinout 10s linear forwards;
    animation: fadeinout 10s linear forwards;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes fadeinout {
  0%,100% { opacity: 0; }
  50% { opacity: 1; }
  }

  @keyframes fadeinout {
  0%,100% { opacity: 0; }
  50% { opacity: 1; }
  }

  span {
    display:inline-block;
     border:1px ;
     padding:3px;
    }

   .a {

   -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
     transform:rotateY(180deg);
     unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
     direction:rtl;}

    .b 

   {  

   -webkit-transform :rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
   -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
    animation:rt 2s forwards 5s;
    }
@-webkit-keyframes rt {
  from{
    -webkit-transform :rotateY(180deg);
  }
  to{
    -webkit-transform :rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
   .c {unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
     direction:rtl;}
```

```html
<section class="elementToFadeInAndOut"<
 <span class="d">
    <span class="d">C</span>
    <span class="d">O</span>
    <span class="d">L</span>
    <span class="d">L</span>
    <span class="d">E</span>
    <span class="d">C</span>
    <span class="d">T</span>
    <span class="d">I</span>
    <span class="d">V</span>
    <span class="d">E</span>
    <span class="d"></span>
    <span class="d">M</span>
    <span class="d">E</span>
    <span class="d">M</span>
    <span class="d">O</span>
    <span class="b">R</span>
    <span class="d">Y</span>
    <span class="d"></span>

    <span class="d"></span></span><br><br>
    </section>
```

Comment: @user3265817 don't forget to add remaining vendor-prefixed such as 
-webkit-, -moz-, -ms-, -o-.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .b {
  animation: rotate 10s ;
  -webkit-animation: rotate 10s ;
}
  @-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
   }
  }
  @keyframes rotate {
    100% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);   

  .c {unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
    direction:rtl;}
```

Comment: Please, explain your solution.